# Set disabled cache but it's not working

Tags: configuration

I'm a newbie in Drupal site development and I'm using Drupal 9.x. In directory web/sites/default I have 2 files:

**settings.php**

```
if (file_exists($app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php')) {
  include $app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php';
}
```

**settings.local.php**

```
<?php

assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE, TRUE);
\Drupal\Component\Assertion\Handle::register();

$settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/development.services.yml';
$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';
$config['system.performance']['css']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
$config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['discovery_migration'] = 'cache.backend.memory';
$settings['cache']['bins']['page'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['rebuild_access'] = TRUE;
$settings['skip_permissions_hardening'] = TRUE;
?>
```

I think this settings are okay but everytime I modify template and reload page it doesnt change, I must go to admin and then clear cache. Please tell me how do I fix it?

Comment: For me permissions seems to have played a part. Changing the owner of `settings.local.php` to `www-data` like the other files there (it was owned by my user after I copied from `example.settings.local.php`) seems to have been the kick that made things finally work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In /sites/default/**settings.local.php** make sure you have

```
$settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/development.services.yml';
```

You need to go to /sites/**development.services.yml** and turn off Twig's cache by adding

```
Parameters:
    twig.config: { debug: true, auto_reload: true, cache: false }
```

This is what mine looks like:

```
# Local development services.
#
# To activate this feature, follow the instructions at the top of the
# 'example.settings.local.php' file, which sits next to this file.
parameters:
    twig.config: { debug: true, auto_reload: true, cache: false }
    http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
```

For more info, see [Disable Drupal 8 caching during development](https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914)